# Excel filtering data set from a database

Tags: database, excel, excel-2007

We have a spreadsheet which summarises a dataset (hidden sheet in the workbook).  There are also drop down filters on the spreadsheet so the users can filter the report to only show certain regions, certain users, date ranges etc.

All of that works but the concern is that the dataset is already 100K rows, and its only been a month.  So the concern is that in order to be able to allow the user to filter results, they have to have ALL the data available.

So is it possible, that when you select different filters from the dropdown, it pulls only the data it needs from the database and puts the dataset into this hidden spreadsheet and the report uses this more limited number of rows?

By the end of the year there could be 700K rows of data, what I am hoping for is that if they use these dropdowns, it only pulls 50K rows from the datasource because thats all they need.

Is there a way to do this?  I know you can set up Microsoft Query but once you create the query, can you dynamically filter the query before pulling the data?

Also, they are stuck on using excel - so alternative platforms (like Access) are unfortunately not possible.

Comment: yes, it's possible and relatively easy. Search for `ADO` and `SQL` programming techniques which could be implemented with `VBA` to your project. There are plenty of information how to do it everywhere in internet.

Comment: Ahh yes... I have experience of that.  But because this is for someone without those skills I wanted to hopefully have more of an out of the box solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PivotTable would seem to meet your requirement - by not extracting any data.